# Know if error exist or not if Swift function

Tags: swift, swift3

Sometimes the function has this structure:

```
func prueba(................, error: Error?){
    //Code here

    //How I can validate if error really exist?
}
```

If I use `if` to make `error!=nil`,  always is not true but the error don't exist.

Comment: in Swift 3 you need to implement do try catch error handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For functions that actually have an optional `Error` parameter, you can do something like this:

```
if let error = error {
    // there is an error, handle as needed
    print("Error: \(error)")
} else {
    // no error
}
```

Comment: I concur but I think it would be better to print error.localizedDescription

Comment: @iDeveloper Developer preference since it's just for debugging and not for the user of the app.

Comment: It's just a preference in the end, and most of the time I display the error to the user in an AlertController.